# VBA to copy current sheet to new workbook and save

Tags: excel, vba

Although I am very rusty on my VBA, I have saved sheets to new workbooks many times before. This code is failing with the error code "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed"

```
wbSource.Sheets(newFileName).Copy

On Error GoTo NewWorkbookError:
Set wbCleaned = ActiveWorkbook
    
ChDir ProcessedFileStoragePath        
wbCleaned.SaveAs filename:=newFilePath, _
                 FileFormat:=FileStoredAsFormat, CreateBackup:=False
```

It is failing with the same error with out the ChDir line, which I added since when recording a macro for saving the new workbook, that code line was in the recording.

The other thing I noticed was the "filename" casing in the .SaveAs method, which should be Filename: but the editor is lowercasing it when I type it in that way. I do NOT have any other variables in this module named filename.

```
 Const ProcessedFileStoragePath As String = "C:\Users\TD\OneDrive\DataLoaders\FilesForAzureStorage\"
Const FileStoredAsFormat As String = "xlCSVUTF8"
```

Any help appreciated, I've spent too much time on this already.

Comment: is the variable newfilepath containing a valid path ?

Comment: Why you copy but never paste the value to new wb?

Comment: When you step throug the code, after the Set line, does wbCleaned give you a name if you try ?wbCleaned.Name in the immediate window?

Comment: Sample values of `newFilePath` and `FileStoredAsFormat` would be helpful.

Comment: @BigBen..yep, realized that when I went to make coffee, added now

Comment: @rohrl77.. yes, I debug printed the wbCleaned name after setting it to ActiveWorkbook and it is in fact the workbook created with the sheet copied over to it.

Comment: Have you tried stripping away the extra settings in the .SaveAs line? To see if one of the variables is the issue?

Comment: @rorhrl77..Thanks, that was the issue, since the file format is an enum, it had to be a variant variable type. all fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue this morning in my own code. ActiveWorkbook for some reason did not yield an object and stayed empty. I got arround the problem by specificing the workbook manually.

Try this:

```
wkb.Worksheets(newFileName).Copy
Excel.Workbooks(2).SaveAs newFilePath
```

SOLUTION:
The solution to the OPs Problem were the file format enum. It had to be a variant variable type (per Comment from OP).

I'll leave my suggestion for others in case it is helpful.

Comment: wbCleaned is NOT nothing, so it is not an empty object. The path i am saving to is a OneDrive path, I thought that might have something to do with it. I tried a plain old "C:\Temp\testfile.csv" and that didnt work either.

Comment: My one extra thought was to test using a different file format

Comment: See my comment reply in the OP